# Migration issue in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, migration

When Migrate website development server to live server, Widget missed theme options missed and some configuration missed. We followed below steps,

1. Take backup of development server both files and database.
2. Moved files to live server and import database to live database.
3. updated configuration details in wp-config.php

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: You need to manually add text widget when you migrate also if use paid theme it has theme options import/export section, you can use it and add import your theme options.

Comment: already happened to me that plugins store paths to resources as absolute path in the database, leading to missing stuff with the new url, just in case, you should make a database search with a keyword from your old domain (not the full url because of encoding)

Answer (score 1):

You have done everything fine 
but when we using options passed theme it is necessary to make changes again when you will move to live server.

Drag you widget again into the same format as it is on the local site. Select themes options again as you selected in the local server these are theme settings issue which is not stored in your database.

So you need to make changes again on your live server.One more thing make sure you theme URL should be changed into wp_options table

For URL change export your database open it into notpade++ editor and then find and replace your all URL from local to live site URL.

Then reimport it into your live site database with the help that you will no need to change URL from a wp_options table and also it will pick up the URL for your images and pages too.

Into the last step reset your permalinks first plains and then post name.

Thanks

Comment: widget and  theme settings not stored in DB?, Then where it stored. Yes I missed to mentioned I updated home and site url.

Comment: because widgets dependent on themes functions.php

Comment: regarding URL change i have updated answer please check it

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have done all above your suggestions. But no solution.